# scrollTop No funciona en Firefox pero Chrome sí(10/07/17)

Tags: jquery, scroll

[image: to top button]
Quizás para ustedes sea una pabada. Estoy haciendo un curso de Jquery e hice un típico boton que te llevan arriba del todo(como el de la foto, pero no es ése). Me funciona en Chrome(versión59.0.3071.115) pero no en Firefox(versión47.0.2). Ya probé cambiar *'body'* por *windows*. El código completo es el siguiente, incluyo desde la etiqueta *body* porque le puse un css inline(etiquetas *html*, *head* las obvio):

```
<body style="height: 1500px">

<center>
    <h1>Hola. Esto es un título</h1>
    <button id="tirararriba" style="margin-top: 1400px">subir</button>
</center>
/*Hasta acá es el html o DOM, no se como se dice*/

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){   
$('#tirararriba').click(function(){
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: 0},500);
});
});
</script>

</body>
```

Gracias!!
PD: La foto es sólo para ilustrar! NO es ése botón una captura de lo que hice!(aunque se nota claramente ya que mi código es hiper básico)

Comment: `$('body,html').animate( ... );` intenta cambiar el selector de esta forma a ver si te corre.

Comment: _cómo lo zupo?_ Crack, era eso, gracias. Aunque no entiendo qué es lo que hice...¿por qué llamar a ambos? No debería entenderlo al llamar al body? y por qué dentro de las mismas comillas? Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Pequeños bugs que de repente tiene Firefox, como el de `width` y `min-width` en css. En este caso firefox piensa que el elemento que tiene el scroll bar es el tag de HTML, por lo que tienes que especificar que también lo detecte para `html`. De hecho la única razón por la que debes dejar body es para compatibilidad con los demás navegadores, si no ya no jala.

Comment: Si quitas `body` te funcionará el evento, para Firefox, pero para los demás navegadores no, hasta donde yo he visto.

Comment: Ahh okok. Mil gracias. Te daría puntos pero no se como se  hace, me acabo de registrar para hacer esta pregunta, ahora me fijo si existe eso en esta página

Comment: Agrego el comentario y explicación como respuesta y ahí ya me puedes dar puntos y poner la respuesta como aceptada

Comment: a mi me sucede al contratio en firefox me funciona pero en chrome no que puede ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox piensa que el elemento que tiene el scrollbar, y por ende al que se le puede aplicar la función de `scrollTop` para animate es el tag de HTML, por lo que cualquiera de estas dos variantes en tu selector pueden funcionar:

```
$('body,html').animate( ... );
//o
$('html').animate( ... );
```

Cabe señalar que la segunda línea sólo funcionará para Firefox, en cualquier otro navegador no hará el scroll, por lo que te recomiendo dejar ambos elementos en el selector, para que tu función sea multi navegador.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="height: 1500px">

<center>
    <h1>Hola. Esto es un título</h1>
    <button id="tirararriba" style="margin-top: 1400px">subir</button>
</center>
/*Hasta acá es el html o DOM, no se como se dice*/

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){   
$('#tirararriba').click(function(){
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0},500);
    //$('html').animate({scrollTop: 0},500); //sólo funcionará en FF
    //$('body').animate({scrollTop: 0},500); // no funcionará en FF
});
});
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Me deja _aceptar respuesta_ pero no se si te está dando los puntos, ya apreté varias veces la flechita para arriba al lado de tu respuesta pero siempre se queda en cero y sale un cartel que dice "Gracias por tu comentario...". Espero te esté pasando esos puntos :s

Comment: Si ya me dió los puntos por respuesta aceptada, gracias